# Python requests PUT and POST command don't work when converted into executable application

Tags: python, python-requests, pyinstaller

I have been trying to use the requests module in Python for an application.
I need to convert all of my application in an executable form in the end.

However, in python the PUT and POST commands are working fine but once the code is converted in an executable then these commands don't work. The GET command works either way.

The code is converted using the pyinstaller module with this command :
`pyinstaller requests_PUT_not_working.py --onefile --noconsole`

My python version is 3.10.2.
My pyinstaller version is 5.1.
My requests version is 2.31.0.

Here is the code with which we tested this behaviour:

```
import requests
import json

# The URL of the resource you want to access
url = "http://192.168.1.88/settings"

# The data you want to send in the request
data = {
    "ipAddress":"192.168.1.87"
    }

# Serialize the data to a JSON formatted string
data_json = json.dumps(data)

# The headers for the request
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Content-Length": str(len(data_json))
}

# Send the request
response = requests.put(url, data=data_json, headers=headers)

# Print the response
print(f"Response Code: {response.status_code}")
print(f"Response Body: {response.text}")
```

The goal of the command i provided was to update the ipAddress of a STM32 micro-controller using the lwip library. When the command works, the ip address is correctly updated.

But, when using the executable, the ip address on the micro-controller become corrupted.
For example, if the address was 192.168.1.57, it will become 0.168.1.57.
This pattern is consistent every time the executable is used.

Thanks in advance,
Martin M.